# Run Function on Most viewWillAppear calls

Tags: ios, swift

I need to run an authentication check on `viewWillAppear` on many different view controllers of varying types, but I obviously don't want to retype it every time. I also need to add a handler variable to pass it to `viewWillDisappear` to end the check.

Can I do this through an extension or protocol (or some other way) so that I can simply include something like (using AuthCheck to flag that I need to run the functions):

`class ForumLanderViewController: UIViewController, AuthCheck {}`

The idea is to hook this in behind the scenes so I can add that one property and it will automatically implement for this controller, without having to implement the variable or functions in the class itself.

I get the idea of using extensions to add new functions to existing classes, but how do I hook into `viewWillAppear` and `viewWillDisappear`, and also pass a variable between them, on specific view controllers, in a simple, DRY way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Protocols let you define sets of methods/properties that all conforming objects have.

A protocol won't do you any good since you want to create behavior for a method that already exists in the base class, `UIViewController`.

Extensions let you add methods/properties to an object, possibly outside of the file that defines that object. However, you can't share the code from an extension among multiple classes unless you tie that code to a common base class.

As @Taier says in their answer, you COULD use method swizzling to replace the implementation of `viewWillAppear`, but I would not recommend that. It relies on Objective-C message dispatch and details of the Objective-C runtime which I suspect will start to be phased out over the next several years.

If you can make all of your classes inherit from a common base class then you can create a custom version of `viewWillAppear` in that base class and that should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Method Swizzling http://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/

> Method swizzling is the process of changing the implementation of an
>   existing selector. It’s a technique made possible by the fact that
>   method invocations in Objective-C can be changed at runtime, by
>   changing how selectors are mapped to underlying functions in a class’s
>   dispatch table.
>
> For example, let’s say we wanted to track how many times each view
>   controller is presented to a user in an iOS app:
>
> Each view controller could add tracking code to its own implementation
>   of viewDidAppear:, but that would make for a ton of duplicated
>   boilerplate code. Subclassing would be another possibility, but it
>   would require subclassing UIViewController, UITableViewController,
>   UINavigationController, and every other view controller class—an
>   approach that would also suffer from code duplication.
>
> Fortunately, there is another way: method swizzling from a category.

Here’s how to do it:

```
private let swizzling: (UIViewController.Type) -> () = { viewController in

    let originalSelector = #selector(viewController.viewWillAppear(_:))
    let swizzledSelector = #selector(viewController.proj_viewWillAppear(animated:))

    let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(viewController, originalSelector)
    let swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(viewController, swizzledSelector)

    method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod) }

extension UIViewController {

    open override class func initialize() {
        // make sure this isn't a subclass
        guard self === UIViewController.self else { return }
        swizzling(self)
    }

    // MARK: - Method Swizzling

    func proj_viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        self.proj_viewWillAppear(animated: animated)

        let viewControllerName = NSStringFromClass(type(of: self))
        print("viewWillAppear: \(viewControllerName)")
    } 
 }
```

Comment: This is technically correct but I would not advise it except in special circumstances and if you really know what you're doing. For one thing, method swizzling doesn't work with native Swift function calls - only Objective-C's dynamic method dispatch, so as the language and the OS evolves it may become unavailable.

Comment: I appreciate the response but I'm also going to heed @Duncan C's advice and avoid swizzling. Thanks to you both!